# React State value not updated in Arrow functional component

Tags: reactjs

React state value not updated in the console but it is updated in the view.

This is my entire code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Add = (props) => {
    console.log("a = ", props.a)
    console.log("b = ", props.b)
    const c = props.a+props.b;
    return (
        <div>
            <p><b>{props.a} + {props.b} = <span style={{'color': 'green'}}>{c}</span></b></p>
        </div>
    )
}

// export default React.memo(Add);

const AddMemo = React.memo(Add);

const MemoDemo = (props) => {

    const [a, setA] = useState(10)
    const [b, setB] = useState(10)
    const [i, setI] = useState(0);

    
    useEffect(() => {
        init()
        return () => {
            console.log("unmounting...")
        }
    }, [])

    const init = () => {
        console.log("init", i)
        setInterval(()=>{
            console.log("i = ", i)
            if(i == 3){
                setA(5)
                setB(5)
            }else{
                setA(10)
                setB(10)
            }
            setI(prevI => prevI+1)
        }, 2000)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>React Memo - demo</h2>
            <p>Function returns previously stored output or cached output. if inputs are same and output should same then no need to recalculation</p>
    <b>I= {i}</b>
            <AddMemo a={a} b={b}/>
        </div>    
    );
}   

export default MemoDemo;
```

Please check this image[image]

Anyone please explain why this working like this and how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as you initialized the `setInterval` once so it would reference to the initial value `i` all the time. Meanwhile, React always reference to the latest one which always reflect the latest value on the UI while your interval is always referencing the old one. So the solution is quite simple, just kill the interval each time your `i` has changed so it will reference the updated value:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    // re-create the interval to ref the updated value
    const id = init();
    return () => {
      // kill this after value changed
      clearInterval(id);
    };
     // watch the `i` to create the interval
  }, [i]);

  const init = () => {
    console.log("init", i);
    // return intervalID to kill
    return setInterval(() => {
      // ... 
    });
  };
```

Comment: I used setTimeout instead of SetInterval like below
useEffect(() => {
        init()
        return () => {
            console.log("unmounting...")
        }
    }, [i])

    const init = () => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("i = ", i)
            if(i >= 3){
                setA(5)
                setB(5)
            }else{
                setA(10)
                setB(10)
            }
            setI(prevI => prevI+1)
        }, 2000)
    }

Answer (score 0):

In callback passed to `setInterval` you have a **[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)** on the value of `i=0`.

For fixing it you can use a reference, log the value in the functional update or use `useEffect`:

```
// Recommended
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(i);
}, [i])


const counterRef = useRef(i);
setInterval(()=> {
  // or
  setI(prevI => {
    console.log(prevI+1);
    return prevI+1;
  })

  // or 
  conosole.log(counterRef.current);
}, 2000);
```