# react setInterval with useState

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

Please check [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/setinterval-fails-35irs)
I am trying the very basic function of changing current value every 2s. The result at beginning is alright, but after 3s or so, it turns out changing very fast. How should fix this setinterval in react?

Comment: try useEffect hook , see here https://upmostly.com/tutorials/setinterval-in-react-components-using-hooks

Comment: Is your question similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63554617/react-state-value-not-updated-in-arrow-functional-component/63554927?

Answer (score 0):

It seems every time the number changes in the page, the setinterval get triggered. It is alright at beginning because there is no 'parallel' setinterval going, but as time elapses, there are many setinterval going at the same time, which causes the number change so quickly.

@dineshkashera's link is valid for this.